# GWT DataGrid with editable sub rows

Tags: datagrid, celltable, gwt-2.5

I have created a DataGrid with GWT 2.5, based on the DataGrid from the GWT showcase. The main difference from there is, that I need editable cells in the sub rows.

When changing the TableBuilder for the sub rows from TextCell to EditTextCell in the code above, editing as such is working.

But this has problems I do not see where they are coming from and how to fix:
- When clicking on a cell in a sub row, editing starts corectly, but the value of the cell in the root row is shown
- after editing, the new value is shown i the cell in the root row. The value in the edited cell is the same as before the editing.

[Here you can see](http://freelancemedia.de/datagrid/) the problem in the sample code from above, just making the cells in the sub rows editable.

When looking at the FieldUpdater of this column, I see that always only the root row is provided as parameter, even when editing a sub row. The subrow information is found correctly in the context internally, but it is not provided to my handlers.

Overwriting the Column and providing back the sub row to the FieldUpdater shows a different problem: all the cells from the edited cell until the root show the new value. When hiding and showing the friends, the values are correct - [As seen here](http://freelancemedia.de/datagrid2/)

I clearly miss something here, about how the DataGrid rendering works. Someone can help me here?

Any help welcome,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to create your own Column, and overwrite onBrowserEvent() or store the respective data object in it.